# Unable install Mongo Driver in PHP 5.3.15

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I had installed mongo server and its working fine in CLI mode, but having issues in running on apache. The mongo PHP extension is not loading in apache web interface. Following are the config info

Info :

```
Server : centos (64bit)
PHP : 5.3.15
mongo Ext version : 1.6
```

Included so file in php.ini and restarted the apache

Extension directory also right as mentioned in `phpinfo();`

Its working with another server with PHP 5.6

I want it to work in PHP 5.3.15

Comment: What commands did you use to install it?